# ServiceStack AuthSession null after modifying a js file in an MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I have a project that uses MVC 4 and ServiceStack, in a web role in an Azure service, hosted for development in IIS Express. I'm using a custom auth provider much like the one in the CustomAuthenticationMvc example project; it authenticates using the Membership class and fills the Roles using the Roles class. I started off developing the page as a straight HTML/CSS/JS page making API calls to ServiceStack and authenticating with a pop-up when it returned a 401, which used to be only when I stopped and restarted the project to rebuild a service. While developing in this form, I could modify static files and reload the page and see the changes without any disruption to the auth session, evidenced by the fact that authenticated API calls would continue to succeed after reloading the page.

Later, once development was mostly complete, I moved the HTML into CSHTML with a controller that just serves it up, added forms authentication, added [Authorize] to the controller, and added code to the Account controller so that when the user logs in, it also authenticates with ServiceStack, again using the code in CustomAuthenticationMvc as a guide. I also added forms redirection hijacking prevention so I could continue to detect unauthenticated API calls. This all works fine, except for this: if I modify a static file such as a JS file and reload the route for the controller that returns the CSHTML, sometimes it reloads just fine, but sometimes the CSHTML will load but then the API calls will result in 401s. This tells me that the forms authentication ticket is still valid, but somehow the API calls are no longer being authenticated. Since all I'm doing is refreshing the browser, the ss cookies should still be there, but if I set a breakpoint on the one line in the controller and check the ServiceStack AuthSession, it is null.

So bottom line, why does changing a JS file in an MVC project sometimes cause the ServiceStack AuthSession to disappear, and is it something that I can fix?

Comment: I suspect that you are not only changing a static JS file. You are also rebuilding your solution in Visual Studio, aren't you? And only in this case you are loosing the session?

Comment: Darin: No, I am only changing the JS file and saving it. I am not rebuilding the project.

Comment: Use Chrome Dev Tools, IE Dev Tools, FireBug, or Fiddler 2 (or whatever) to check the cookies yourself and verify that they're still there or if they've been wiped out.

Comment: Mike P: Confirmed, the cookies are indeed still there on the request that is 401 unauthorized. The .ASPXAUTH cookie's position changed from just before the SS cookies to after them, perhaps suggesting that the original cookie was removed and a new one added. However, when I was about to go through the steps again to compare the actual contents of the cookie, the problem stopped occurring. Changes to the JS are being reflected on the page with a simple refresh. Maddening! Perhaps it's a VS or IIS Express issue?

Comment: This is happening to me too; but, I have this issue only on a single windows configuration: Parallel virtual machine on a Mac. I don't see this problem when I am developing on a full Windows 7 Pro or Windows Server 2008.

Comment: After reporting this issue, I noticed that I had some windows updates pending. I rebooted and now the issue is not as reliably reproducible, though it does still happen occasionally. So it might have been an issue with VS or IIS Express.